# PyQT Cannot queue QTextCursor - how to properly change window content

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Long story short, again. I'm writing python library for very simple text output to Qt's QTextBrowser window (stored in window.ui). As far as I found before, Qt objects should not be accessed directly. So, what is the right way to get rid from:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

errors when 'printing' from other thread?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
import sys
import time


def async(func):
    from threading import Thread
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func_hl = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        func_hl.start()
        return func_hl
    return async_func


class GuiFile(QObject):   # add also GUI_FORM
    def __init__(self, filename):
        QObject.__init__(self, None)
        self.filename = filename
        self.myapp = sys.argv
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(self.myapp)

    def show(self):
        self.window = uic.loadUi(self.filename)
        self.window.show()


    def pprint(self, text):
        gui_object = self.window.outbox
        gui_object.insertHtml(text + '<br>')
        gui_object.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    @async
    def other_thead():
        time.sleep(1)
        for x in xrange(3):
            print x
            gui.pprint(u'Hello %s' % x)

    gui = GuiFile('window.ui')
    gui.show()
    other_thead()
    sys.exit(gui.app.exec_())
```

Please tell me explicitly, 'cus I'm totally stuck and confused reading about those slots and Qt theads.

window.ui link is here: https://yadi.sk/d/U3esbMcIkvbFc

**upd1:**

also I've tried to emit signals like that:

```
    self.connect(self.window.outbox, SIGNAL("print"), self.real_print)


    def real_print(self, text, **kwargs):
        print 'RP'
        gui_object = self.window.outbox

        """ What if we print to other field? """

        if kwargs.get('field'):
            field = kwargs['field']

            for elem in dir(self.window):
                if str(elem) == field:
                    gui_object = getattr(self.window, elem)

        gui_object.insertHtml(text + '<br>')
        gui_object.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    def pprint(self, text, **kwargs):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("print"), text)
```

but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my god, it's solved!

```
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("print"), self.real_print)
```